# how to pass model data to policy class from blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Hello i'm facing a problem of laravel, gate,i'm trying to pass Model class data to the gate function and check some data of the model class.
but problem is can't pass the model to gate function from the blade file.

this is my model,AuthServiceProviderand view file code.

view.blade.php

```
 @can('create-role',permission::class)
                 <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-rounded mb- 
                     4">Add</a>
                    </div>
                @endcan
```

AuthServiceProvider.php

```
    Gate::define('create-role', function ( $permissionrole) {
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
         $permissionid = 1;   

        foreach ($permissionrole as $value) {          
      if($value->user_id == $id && $value->permisions_id == $permissionid)
            {
                return  true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        });  
}
```

Model file

```
  protected $table = 'permissions';
  protected $primaryKey  = 'permission_id';
  protected $fillable = [
  name','for',]; 
  public $incrementing = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the `permission` model instead of `permission::class` in the `@can` directive ; then you have access to it:

```
      Gate::define('create-role', function ( $permission) {
      $id = Auth::user()->id;
      $permissionid = 1;

      //your checking goes here
      });
```